# Change the configuration of the task uglify dynamically

Tags: gruntjs

I need to change configuration of my uglify task for only minify file as needed (as explained here for the jshint task : https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-watch#compiling-files-as-needed)

The modification works well for the jshint task but not for uglify, i think the problem is the property path...

Any help would be appreciated ;)

Here is my Gruntfile.js :

```js
module.exports = function (grunt) {
    grunt.initConfig({

        // define source files and their destinations
        jshint: {
            all: ['dev/**/*.js'],
        },
        uglify: {
            dynamic_mappings: {
              // Grunt will search for "**/*.js" under "dev/" when the "minify" task
              // runs and build the appropriate src-dest file mappings then, so you
              // don't need to update the Gruntfile when files are added or removed.
            files: [{
                  expand: true,     // Enable dynamic expansion.
                  cwd: 'dev/',      // Src matches are relative to this path.
                  src: ['**/*.js'], // Actual pattern(s) to match.
                  dest: 'build',   // Destination path prefix.
                  ext: '.min.js',   // Dest filepaths will have this extension.
                },
              ],
            }
        }
        watch: {
        options: { spawn: false },
            js:  { files: 'dev/**/*.js', tasks: [ 'uglify' ] },
        }
    });

    // load plugins
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-jshint');

    // default task
    grunt.registerTask('default', [ 'watch' ]);

    grunt.event.on('watch', function(action, filepath) {
        grunt.config(['jshint', 'all'], filepath);
        grunt.config('uglify.dynamic_mappings.files', [{src: filepath }]);
    });

};
```

Comment: I haven't tried this, but it is possible that the files config statement is completely replacing your files config.  Have you tried providing all attributes (expand, cwd,etc…) when you modify the uglify config?

Comment: That was the solution! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The line

```
grunt.config('uglify.dynamic_mappings.files', [{src: filepath }]);
```

Is completely replacing the original configuration for uglify.dynamic_mappings.files

Instead try including the other original parameters along with the new src: filepath

Answer (score 0):

How to not minify already minified on each "grunt build" in yeoman

```
   uglify:        {
      onlyScripts: {
        files:   [{
          dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/scripts/scripts.js',
          src:  ['.tmp/concat/scripts/scripts.js']
        }]
      }
    }
```

Also, now uglify will not copy your vendor.js from temporary folder, so add "vendorJS" section to "copy" task:

```
copy:
      //...
      vendorJS: {
        expand: true,
        cwd:    '.tmp/concat/scripts/',
        dest:   '<%= yeoman.dist %>/scripts/',
        src:    'vendor.js'
      }
```

Then, in "build" task, set target of uglify to 'onlyScripts' and copy vendor.js:

```
  grunt.registerTask('build', [
    'jshint',
    'clean:dist',
    //'wiredep',
    // ...
    'useminPrepare',
    //'concurrent:dist',
    'autoprefixer',
    'concat',
    'ngAnnotate',
    'copy:dist',
    'cssmin',
    'uglify:onlyScripts',
    'copy:vendorJS',
   // ...
  ]);
```

http://eugenioz.blogspot.in/2014/08/how-to-not-minify-already-minified-on.html